# Rails 4: Generate Scaffold Controller with existed Model, it only works after reloading page twice

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I generate Model first

> rails g model cat name

Then I genarate Scaffold Controller with the model name

> rails g scaffold_controller zoo/cat name --model-name=zoo/cat

Then I add route

> namespace :zoo do
>   resources :cats
>   end

Then I edit the Model

> class Zoo::Cat < ActiveRecord::Base
>   end

The funny thing is it fails at first, with error

> LoadError in Zoo::CatsController#index
>   Unable to autoload constant Cat, expected /home/minh/Desktop/fnl110/app/models/cat.rb to define it
>     def index
>       @zoo_cats = Zoo::Cat.all
>     end

**Then I reload the page, it works without any error**. Here is what server said:

```
Started GET "/zoo/cats" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-01-10 21:05:30 +0700
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.1ms)  SELECT `schema_migrations`.* FROM `schema_migrations`
Processing by Zoo::CatsController#index as HTML
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 14ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

LoadError (Unable to autoload constant Cat, expected /home/minh/Desktop/fnl110/app/models/cat.rb to define it):
  app/controllers/zoo/cats_controller.rb:7:in `index'


  Rendered /home/minh/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (7.1ms)
  Rendered /home/minh/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (3.2ms)
  Rendered /home/minh/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (1.2ms)
  Rendered /home/minh/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout (29.2ms)
  Rendered /home/minh/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/_markup.html.erb (0.5ms)
  Rendered /home/minh/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/_inner_console_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.4ms)
  Rendered /home/minh/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/_prompt_box_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.3ms)
  Rendered /home/minh/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/style.css.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.4ms)
  Rendered /home/minh/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/console.js.erb within layouts/javascript (19.6ms)
  Rendered /home/minh/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/main.js.erb within layouts/javascript (0.5ms)
  Rendered /home/minh/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/error_page.js.erb within layouts/javascript (0.6ms)
  Rendered /home/minh/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/index.html.erb (42.4ms)


Started GET "/zoo/cats" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-01-10 21:10:15 +0700
Processing by Zoo::CatsController#index as HTML
  Zoo::Cat Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `cats`.* FROM `cats`
  Rendered zoo/cats/index.html.erb within layouts/application (8.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 200ms (Views: 197.5ms | ActiveRecord: 1.2ms)


Started GET "/assets/animal/bears.self-e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-01-10 21:10:16 +0700


Started GET "/assets/animal/cats.self-e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-01-10 21:10:16 +0700


Started GET "/assets/animal/dogs.self-e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-01-10 21:10:16 +0700


Started GET "/assets/scaffolds.self-d5c911709e0018272624ff2abf5748b5d0ff72c54f791bb9bcefd817c3322285.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-01-10 21:10:16 +0700


Started GET "/assets/turbolinks.self-c37727e9bd6b2735da5c311aa83fead54ed0be6cc8bd9a65309e9c5abe2cbfff.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-01-10 21:10:16 +0700


Started GET "/assets/jquery_ujs.self-d456baa54c1fa6be2ec3711f0a72ddf7a5b2f34a6b4f515f33767d6207b7d4b3.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-01-10 21:10:16 +0700


Started GET "/assets/application.self-e80e8f2318043e8af94dddc2adad5a4f09739a8ebb323b3ab31cd71d45fd9113.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-01-10 21:10:16 +0700


Started GET "/assets/animal/bears.self-877aef30ae1b040ab8a3aba4e3e309a11d7f2612f44dde450b5c157aa5f95c05.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-01-10 21:10:16 +0700


Started GET "/assets/jquery.self-a714331225dda820228db323939889f149aec0127aeb06255646b616ba1ca419.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-01-10 21:10:16 +0700


Started GET "/assets/animal/dogs.self-877aef30ae1b040ab8a3aba4e3e309a11d7f2612f44dde450b5c157aa5f95c05.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-01-10 21:10:16 +0700


Started GET "/assets/application.self-3b8dabdc891efe46b9a144b400ad69e37d7e5876bdc39dee783419a69d7ca819.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-01-10 21:10:16 +0700


Started GET "/assets/animal/cats.self-877aef30ae1b040ab8a3aba4e3e309a11d7f2612f44dde450b5c157aa5f95c05.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-01-10 21:10:16 +0700
```

P/S: The reason of

> rails g scaffold_controller zoo/cat name --model-name=zoo/cat

is

> rails g scaffold_controller zoo/cat --model-name=zoo/cat
>   => controller doesn't take model attributes

and

> rails g scaffold_controller zoo/cat --model-name=cat
>   =>  Error: undefined local variable or method `new_cat_path'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is normal, your model should be moved in the zoo directory, so `app/models/zoo/cat.rb` (instead of `app/models/cat.rb`). If you do that it will work immediately.

I might be wrong, but I believe the following happens:

1. When you load the page the first time, rails will lazily load the models, and will give you the error not because of the request, but because the file `app/models/cat.rb` should define `Cat` and not `Zoo::Cat`;
2. Even with the error, rails will have loaded the `Zoo::Cat` model, so when you reload the page, it won't encounter the error because the models have already been loaded, thus the request succeeds.

Comment: Is there a way to use several controller in namespace with one non-namespace Model only?

Comment: Of course, but in that case you need to define your model outside the namespace and refer to it in the same way (i.e. Cat and not Zoo::Cat).